# Convert RSS feed in one line

Tags: looking-for-a-script, rss

I need to use an RSS Feed in a Digital Signage application (Xibo).
But to scroll the feed on right or left I need it to be presented on a single line or only the first line will be displayed.

I've looked at Yahoo Pipes but don't seams to make it, does anyone know a webapp or software i can use to convert the multi-line RSS Feed into one single line?

Comment: Use http://goo.gl to shortner the main RSS url. It'll 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Reformat the RSS feed using a PHP XML parser such as http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/ you can either use the reformatted RSS feed, or create a string from the feed properties and send it to Xibo

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds can be styled using XSLT stylesheets.  I've never seen one that will reformat one into a single line, but it should be possible to do.  Here is an article that tells you how to use XSLT with RSS: http://www.paulwest.co.uk/article.php/styling-rss-news-feeds-with-xslt